# How to replace certain parts of a string using a list?

Tags: python, string, list

```
namelist = ['John', 'Maria']
e_text = 'John is hunting, Maria is cooking'
```

I need to replace 'John' and 'Maria'. How can I do this?

I tried:

```
for name in namelist:
    if name in e_text:
        e_text.replace(name, 'replaced')
```

But it only works with 'John'. The output is: 'replaced is hunting, Maria is cooking'. How can I replace the two names?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please give sample input and output

Comment: Check here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-replace-substring-in-list-of-strings/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable in python, so replacements don't modify the string, only return a modified string. You should reassign the string:

```py
for name in namelist:
    e_text = e_text.replace(name, "replaced")
```

You don't need the `if name in e_text` check since `replace` already does nothing if it's not found.

Comment: Hello. This only replaced the last item of the list.

Comment: Did you assign to the same variable name or a different variable name? It is important that it is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You could form a regex alteration of names and then `re.sub` on that:

```py
namelist = ['John', 'Maria']
pattern = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(namelist) + r')\b'
e_text = 'John is hunting, Maria is cooking'
output = re.sub(pattern, 'replaced', e_text)
print(e_text + '\n' + output)
```

This prints:

```
John is hunting, Maria is cooking
replaced is hunting, replaced is cooking
```